# QtCreator identifies a memory leak on the line of code that starts a QThread

Tags: qt, memory-leaks

I'm starting to create a music player. and I'm dabling in doing the spectrum analyzer. Here is the thing. When ever my data buffer fills I start a thread that does the FFT of the data buffer.

I've recently detected a memory leak. It is very slow, but clear. I used the memcheck tool of qtcreator and got this:

```
768 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 13,626 of 14,267
  in SpectrumController::processBuffer() in /home/ariela/repos/cmp/spectrumcontroller.cpp:105
```

The line pointed to this: fft.start();

In effect if I avoid (by commenting) the parts of the program that do de calculations (the fft thread) and just draw a random number of values, then the memory leak disappears.

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT:

The only part of the program I modified is this. Wheneever there is enough data for processing the fuction processBuffer is called. Here is what it does:

```
void SpectrumController::processBuffer(){
    if (!dataBuffer.isEmpty()){
        if (!isRunning){
            fft.setInput(dataBuffer.first());
            dataBuffer.removeFirst();
            //qWarning() << "Data buffer size" << dataBuffer.size();
            fft.start(); // Line marked as the line of code with the memory leak.
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If I do this the memory leak is gone:

```
void SpectrumController::processBuffer(){
    if (!dataBuffer.isEmpty()){
        if (!isRunning){
            fft.setInput(dataBuffer.first());
            dataBuffer.clear();  // I need to clear the buffer since it fills up much faster when not doing the actual calculations.
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it might be my buffer growing but in the first section of code I printed out the buffer size and it oscilates between 0 and 1 so that is not it.

In the second version since isRunning never becomes true the buffer fills much faster so I changed remover first to clear. And effectively the leak stopped.

The function called on fft finished signal simply updates the bar graph.

Comment: can you add some more code to this? Like the things you comment out would be a good start

Comment: Code is really long. I added some to examplify better. Hope is enough

Comment: no not really. Is `fft`one of your types or a qt type? if so which one? when yours what does start do? Are you using `new` anywhere?

Comment: I thought it was clear because of the title. It is a QThread. Its run method does the fft of the vector set by setInput.

Comment: Ah ok. Is this thread still running when you end your process?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. When the thread is finished it call a method that draws some bars on the screen based on its outpu. And as soon as there is enought data to do another fft, processBuffer starts it again.